# use R Shiny inputs to divide column for ggplot axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the following code and would essentially like to take two inputs and return an outplot of a plot with time on the x-axis and the y axis being a ratio of input1/input2. I have tried with aes and aes_string but can not seem to get a working block displaying the ratio inside the shiny app. (Have no problems plotting input1 against year.

```
ui <- navbarPage("y",
  tabPanel('Teacher Type Comparison',
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                selectInput('teacherInputOne', 'Compare ratio of',
                           choices = teacher_inputs, selected = 'male_total_staff'),
                selectInput('teacherInputTwo', 'to ratio of:',
                           choices = teacher_inputs,  selected = 'female_total_staff'),
                checkboxGroupInput('teacherState','States / Territories',area_names)
            ),

            mainPanel(
            plotOutput('teacherTypePlot'))
        )
    )


  )
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$teacherTypePlot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(data = data, aes(x= year, y = (input$teacherInputOne / input$teacherInputTwo))) + geom_line(aes(colour = state))
    })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand all of your variables, based on the code provided, but I would change the server to filter your data based on the input selections in the UI to pass the filtered values to your Y aes. I have only proposed changing code in the server:

```
    server <- function(input, output) {

      output$teacherTypePlot <- renderPlot({


        data <- data %>% 
          filter(var1 == input$teacherInputOne, 
                 var2 == input$teacherInputTwo)

        ggplot(data = data, aes(x= year, y = var3)) + 
          geom_line(aes(colour = state))
      })}
```

Comment: I would like the input to be two seperate column names, and the ratio  of these two columns is the y axis of the plot.